# Convert NSDate in12 Hour Format To 24 Hour Format

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an `NSDate` Object which is in 12 hour format like `2014-09-16 04:40:05 pm +0000`.

I want to convert this into 24 hour format and want to get back an NSDate object like `2014-09-16 16:40:05 +0000`.

Can some one guide me in doing that.

So i want some method like :

```
-(NSDate *) get24HourFormat:(NSDate *) date{

  return date object;
}
```

Comment: ... and 5000 other questions.

Answer (score 5):

Simple use this:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 dateformate.dateFormat = @"HH:mm a"; // Date formater
 NSString *timeString = [dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; // Convert date to string
 NSLog(@"timeString :%@",timeString);
```

Logic: Simply convert date format **hh:mm** to **HH:mm**

Comment: so what i want is if its 3:30 pm then i should get 15:30 and no am or pm.

Comment: ya dude. just delete "a". write only HH:mm. "a" for am/pm

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateformate.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // Date formater
 NSString *timeString = [dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; // Convert date to string
NSLog(@"timeString :%@",timeString);

Comment: its not working still giving me 3:38 pm

Comment: clean your code and run. My output is: timeString :2014-09-16 18:11:40

Comment: You got it or still u r struggling ?

Comment: still struggling... is your iphone is 12 hourb format or 24 hour

Comment: 12 hr format. in my device and simulator also its working fine. check ur code and ur device format

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a deep misunderstanding here what `NSDate` is and does.

An `NSDate` object is a point in time in `UTC`. It doesn't have a time zone. It doesn't have a format. It has nothing. You can't change its format, it doesn't even make any sense.

What you can do is to use an `NSDateFormatter` to convert the `NSDate` to a string. By default, `NSDateFormatter` uses your local time zone, which means for most people that the result will be different from the result that `NSLog` would show for an `NSDate`. In the `NSDateFormatter`, you can use whatever settings you want.

Usually you would respect how the user set up his date formatting and not change it for anything that is visible to the user. As a user, if I had set up my device to show days in 12 hour format, I'd be very annoyed if your application worked differently.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
 -(NSString *)changeformate_string24hr:(NSString *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

    NSDate* wakeTime = [df dateFromString:date];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];


    return [df stringFromDate:wakeTime];

}

-(NSString *)changeformate_string12hr:(NSString *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate* wakeTime = [df dateFromString:date];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

    return [df stringFromDate:wakeTime];

}
```

Comment: How can i convert my date to string...

Comment: NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:yourDate];

Comment: NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];     [formatter stringFromDate:yourDate]; is not working in the above method it returns nil

Comment: in above method they return string, so no need to convert...

Comment: Use my method u can easily get a date in string @Abdul Samad